# Setting field required and empty value

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to set the age drop down as a required field. Also setting an empty "--" value, so that a value must be selected. Currently, people just leave it as "18" because it is already there.

Here is an example of having a required field:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input  type="text" id="guestUsername" class="form-control fadeIn second" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the field I need to modify and unsure how to:

```
<div class="row form-group fadeIn second">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" name="age" id="age">
             <?php for($age=18;$age<99;$age++):?>
             <option value="<?=$age?>"><?=$age?> years</option>
             <?php endfor;?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty `<option>` before outputting the rest of the dropdown values. Then if it is empty when the form is submitted you can throw an error.

```
<select class="form-control" name="age" id="age" required>
     <option></option>
     <?php for($age=18;$age<99;$age++):?>
     <option value="<?=$age?>"><?=$age?> years</option>
     <?php endfor;?>
</select>
```

Sample

```html
<form>
<select class="form-control" name="age" id="age" required>
    <option>AGE</option>
    <option value="18">18 years</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: How can I place a non value as the first option. For example if I'd like it to display "Age" in the box, but not allow this as a valid value?

Comment: Just add it like you would any test in an `<option>` tag.

Comment: Was able to find this code that worked for this part:
<option value="" disabled selected>Age</option>

Answer (score 0):

Try to check it before submitting form. If the user selects first option show the alert message, if not submit the form.

```
<form method="POST" id="myForm">
<select class="form-control" name="age" id="age" required>
<option>AGE</option>
<option value="18">18 Years</option>
</select>
</form>
<button onclick="Validate()">Submit</button>
<script>
function Validate(){
var a = document.getElementById('age').selectedIndex; 
var b = document.getElementById('myForm'); 
if(a=="0"){
alert("Please Choose A Valid Option");
}else{
b.submit();
}
}
</script>
```